# ggplot graph inconsistent with observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to create a graph that visualizes the evolution of 4 variables. The ggplot produced, however, is not consistent with the observations. What might be the problem here?

```
Data <- data.frame(
Wind = c(236,325,470,615,647,821),
Hard_coal= c(591,811,667,681,532,344),
Gas= c(883,841,472,731,678,680),
Bio = c(883,841,811,731,678,680),
year= c("2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020"))


#create the plot
```

```
ggp <- ggplot(Data, aes(year))+geom_line(aes(y = Wind, (size = 1.5)), group = 1)+geom_line(aes(y = Hard_coal), group = 2)+geom_line(aes(y = Gas), group = 3)+geom_line(aes(y = Bio), group = 4)+scale_x_discrete()
```

#plot

`ggp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reshape the data in [tidy](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) format

```r
library(tidyverse)

Data <- data.frame(
  Wind = c(236,325,470,615,647,821),
  Hard_coal= c(591,811,667,681,532,344),
  Gas= c(883,841,472,731,678,680),
  Bio = c(883,841,811,731,678,680),
  year= c("2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020"))

Data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = value, color = name, group = name, linetype = name)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I used `facet_wrap()` and adjusted the x axis

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

df_melt<-melt(df, id.vars=c("Year"))
df_melt<-as.data.frame(df_melt)


ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=Year, y=value, group=variable)) +  
  geom_line(aes(color=variable), size=3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~as.factor(variable) )+
  labs(x="Year", y="Value", title="") + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,  face="bold", size=20, color="black")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))
```

[image]

You may want to highlight specific points, to do so use `geom_vline()`

```
df_melt<-melt(df, id.vars=c("Year"))
df_melt<-as.data.frame(df_melt)


ggplot(df_melt, aes(x=Year, y=value, group=variable)) +  
  geom_line(aes(color=variable), size=3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c("2016", "2019"),col = "black", lwd = 2, lty=2) +
  facet_wrap(~as.factor(variable) )+
  labs(x="Year", y="Value", title="") + 
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,  face="bold", size=20, color="black")) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text( hjust = 1,  face="bold", size=14, color="black") )+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=16, color="black"))
```

[image]